# Emptying a queue in Tkinter using after()

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I have an app in `tkinter` which receives messages from several websockets at the same time. In order to process these sequentially and avoid race conditions I add each message to a `Queue` as they arrive, and process them sequentially, like so:

```
def queue_msg(self, msg):
    self.queue.put(msg)

def process_queue(self):
    try:
        msg = self.queue.get(0)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        ...do stuff...
    self.master.after(10, self.process_queue)
```

The `self.process_queue()` function just keeps calling itself as long as the app is running so that all messages are handled smoothly in the background. So far so good.

I have several operations in the code for which I need to pause new messages from being processed. When these occur, I would like the app to 1) stop adding new messages to the queue, 2) process all the messages that are already on the queue, 3) do the operation, and 4) start adding messages to the queue again. Dropping the messages that arrive in the interim is fine.

My first attempt at this was to define a class variable `self.pause`, have these operations set this to `True`, and simply check this condition when receiving new messages:

```
def queue_msg(self, msg):
    if not self.pause:
        self.queue.put(msg)

def process_queue(self):
    try:
        msg = self.queue.get(0)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        ...do stuff...
    self.master.after(10, self.process_queue)

def sensitive_operation(self):
    self.pause = True
    while self.queue.qsize() > 0:
        continue
    ....do stuff....
    self.pause = False
```

But this fails. Either qsize() is already 0, in which case for some reason `self.pause` usually appears to stay `False` after `sensitive_operation()` exits, or it gets stuck in an infinite loop at the `continue`.

Apparently I am misunderstanding something about the `after()` method, because clearly changes to `self.pause` are not being consistently propagated through the various callbacks. Can someone help me understand what's going on behind the scenes here, and maybe suggest a better way to pause and empty the queue when necessary?

Here is a minimal working example. To simulate message arrivals from a websocket I have the process_message() function randomly adding messages to the queue as it processes them. Pressing the `pause` button will work most of the time, but if you mash it a few times eventually it will hang at the `continue`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import Queue
import numpy as np

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        parent.deiconify()
        self.parent = parent
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.pause = False
        self.parent.after(1000, self.process_message)
        self.pause_button = tk.Button(parent, text='Pause', command = self.pause_and_empty)
        self.pause_button.pack()

    def queue_message(self, message):
        if not self.pause:
            self.queue.put(message)

    def process_message(self):
        try:
            message = self.queue.get(0)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            print message
        rand = np.random.rand()
        if rand < 0.2:
            self.queue_message('test message: {0}'.format(rand))
        self.parent.after(10, self.process_message)

    def pause_and_empty(self):
        self.pause = True
        while self.queue.qsize() > 0:
            print 'stuck!'
            continue
        print 'made it!'
        self.pause = False

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT 2: based on the first answer, the following tweak to the `pause_and_empty` function seems to do the trick:

```
def pause_and_empty(self):
        self.pause = True
        if self.queue.qsize() > 0:
            self.parent.after(10, self.pause_and_empty)
        print 'made it!'
```

Comment: This clearly needs [mcve].

Comment: Fair enough, I'll work on that.

Comment: @Nae I added an MWE

Answer (score 1):

When `widget.after(milliseconds, callback, *args)` is read, it queues a timer event that calls `callback` with `*args` *after* `milliseconds`. After the method is finished, [python](/questions/tagged/python) *goes back* to `mainloop` line.

The queue in the example never stops as the call to `process_message` never stops, because why should it? `self.pause` is set `False` but `process_message` never checks that whether it's `True` or not.

Comment: I see - I guess I misunderstood how `after` worked. I will take another crack at it. I don't want `process_message` to ever stop, since the pause ends eventually. During the pause I just want `queue_message` to stop adding things to the queue.

I have edited with a tweak to the pause_and_empty function based on your feedback. It seems to work as intended now. Can you confirm/deny?